# How to make text input left align when onblur?

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to make the text, within a text input box, align left when the blur state is triggered (using css/javascript/jquery). By 'align left' i mean that I want to see the first letter of the text back in view. 
In order to reproduce this, the length of the text must overflow past the end of the text box and the cursor must be towards the end of the line of text. If you then click outside of the text box, the text does not revert back to the beginning of the line - this occurs in Firefox (I am using v40.0.3) and IE Edge. Chrome behaves in the way that I want it to.

```
<input type="text" style="width:100px;" value="This is a piece of text that goes beyond the end of the text field.">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ub6uro3m/

Any ideas how to get this to work across all browsers?

Comment: Do you have any example code to recreate your problem?

Comment: it does align left when blurred...

Comment: In Fiirefox, when the cursor is positioned at the end of the text ?

Comment: Interesting issue you found there.. I just tried it on FF 39.0.3 to see if it was a recent bug, but the same behaviour persists.

Comment: It happens in Firefox and IE Edge, but Chrome seems to send the position back to the beginning of the text, whihc is the behaviour I want across all browsers.